# Changing the color of the rticklabels in a polar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, label, polar-coordinates

I want to change the color of the rticklabels in a polar plot to white.
It works with

```
ax.set_rgrids([1., 2., 3.], color='white')
```

However, using `set_rgrids` I have to give the positions of the ticklabels. I would rather like to use the standard positions, such that I don't have to think about their values for different data sets.

I there a way to directly access and change the color of the rticklabels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way:  for a polar plot, `theta` and `r` map onto `x` and `y` respectively for the generic axis actions.  So - you just do

```
rlabels = ax.get_ymajorticklabels()
for label in rlabels:
    label.set_color('white')
```

[Documentation for `get_ymajorticklabels()`](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.0/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_ymajorticklabels) shows that it returns a list of `Text` objects - the actions you can perform on a `Text` object are [in the docs](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.0/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text).

Comment: the `label.set_color()` seems to affect the plot's background. it turns actually transparent (at least in jupyter notebooks in vscode). giving the `figure()` call a `facecolor="white"` addresses that